# How is $|xy^{2}z| < 2^{p+1}$ (Pumping Lemma application)

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

In the Question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/proving-l-a2n-n-ge-0-is-not-regular-by-use-of-pumping-lem) it is said that

> $|xy^2z|<2^{p+1}$

Considering that $|x| = 0$ and $|z| = 0$, y consists of $2^{p}$. It's probably trivial, but how do I see, that $|xy^2z| < 2^{p+1}$?

Comment: It can't be the case that both $|x| = 0$ and $|z| = 0$.
By property b) you have $|xy| \leq p$, so if $|x|, |z| = 0$ then $|xyz| = |y| \leq |xy| \leq p < 2^p = |a^{2^p}|$ ↯

Comment: But if $|y| = p$, $|xy| <= p$ would be satisfied, no?

Comment: Okay I get it, $|y|$ can't consist of $2^p$ because of $|xy| <= p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question you've linked, we have $|xy| = |x| + |y| \leq p$ (property b) so $|y| \leq p$ since $|x| \geq 0$.
Therefore
$$|xy^2z| = |xyz| + |y| = 2^p + |y| \leq 2^p + p < 2^{p + 1}.$$

Comment: what if I pump up i? $|xyz| + |y| + |y| + ... \geq 2^p+p$ EDIT: Then it's the same game again, it's bigger than $2^{p+1}$ but smaller than $2^{p+2}$ etc...